# After changing AppDelegate to Objective-C++, can't addSubview to UIWindow anymore

Tags: iphone, objective-c++, uiwindow, addsubview, openfeint

After adding OpenFeintX, I had to change my AppDelegate to (.mm). Not sure f this is absolutely the reason of the issue but it seems like the only thing that changed.

Now, anything that I addSubview to the UIWindow doesn't actually show. If I put a video, it still plays but shows nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Everything worked before you made this change?

Comment: Did you make the corresponding changes in the xib file?

Comment: @Karoly Yes, everything worked fine before that change.

Comment: @Praveen What changes are you talking about in the xib file? I didn't change anything in the XIB files.

Comment: Did you then update where you include the AppDelegate with #import "YourAppDelegate.mm", or however that might look?

Comment: [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:myVC]; worked and showed the view but it is still not a solution I'm looking for since it's not very elegant and doesn't really serve my purpose.

Comment: Hmm, really, the only thing that I could think of that would cause it to break all of a sudden is that your various file references are out of date/incorrect, and changing the file type would do just that. If they are updated however, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Did the app delegate's etc change in the xib after you made the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve the issue. It seems like, for some still unknown reason, the **viewDidLoad** and **viewWillAppear** of my viewController were both **called** before the **application didFinishLaunch**. So every time I added a subview, it would add it to a UIWindow that doesn't exist yet. I **moved my code to viewDidAppear** and that **fixed it**.

**If you have a similar issue**, **check the memory location** of the UIWindow and make sure it is the same UIWindow, you were adding the subview to.